# Broadcasting Data from one socket thread to all existing socket threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

i've a ServerSocket that listen to connections on a particular address and port and for each connection(client) make a thread in order to implement a stateful protocol,now each thread(client) messages process in it's own thread,here is the problem:

1.How can i send data from one thread(client socket) to all(simply broadcasting a message.),i see some sort of BlockingQueues between two threads,here i've one to many threads for broadcasting and also have a one to one model for private messages.

2.I see a Synchronized block solution for share a data or resource between threads but here in my code i have no idea where should i implement this and why?

---

Entry Point to the server,Where the ServerSocket Is initialized and Listen:

```
public class ServerStarter {
    //All Users that creates from threads adding here.
    public static Hashtable<String,User> users = new Hashtable<String,User>(); 
    //All Channels add here.
    public static Hashtable<String,Channel> channels = new Hashtable<String,Channel>(); 
    final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Config config = new Config();
        ServerSocket Server = null;
        try {
            //server configs,from left to right is: PORT,BackLog,Address
            Server = new ServerSocket(config.port, config.backlog,config.ServerIP);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        while (true) {
            Socket sock = null;
            BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
            try {
                sock = Server.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (Server != null && !Server.isClosed()) {
                    try {
                        Server.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1)
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                }
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            try {
                inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            //each clients run on it's own thread!
            new SocketThread(sock,inFromClient).start();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Where The Client Socket Threads Create is Here:

```
public class SocketThread extends Thread {
    Socket csocket;
    BufferedReader inFromClient;

    public SocketThread(Socket csocket, BufferedReader inFromClient) {
        this.csocket = csocket;
        this.inFromClient = inFromClient;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
            //some primary informations sent to server for further processing.
            RequestHandler Reqhandler = new RequestHandler(this.getId(), fromclient);
            System.out.println("=======================================");
            while (true) {
                fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
                IRCParser parser = new IRCParser(fromclient);
                //if the primary info's are OK and nothing causes to kill the thread the clients go to the infinite loop for processing messages.
                Reqhandler.Commandhandler(parser.getCommand(), parser.getParameters());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //kill current thread!
            currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

if the classes and other data is not sufficient,tell me to add more code and commenting,tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you just need something which passes the message from one client thread to other client threads. I think you should be able to use observer pattern here.

Something like this - (please note that i have removed all other things from your code which were not required to show the message broadcasting concept. You might need to change it back as per your requirement).

```
public class ServerStarter {

    private static final ServerStarter singleton = new ServerStarter();

    private volatile boolean shutdown;
    // thread pool executor
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    // observable to notify client threads
    private final Observable observable = new Observable();
    // fair lock (can use unfair lock if message broadcasting order is not important)
    private final Lock fairLock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    private ServerStarter() {
    }

    public static ServerStarter getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            //server configs,from left to right is: PORT,BackLog,Address
            server = new ServerSocket();
            while (!ServerStarter.getInstance().isShutdown()) {
                Socket sock = server.accept();
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                //each clients run on it's own thread!
                SocketThread clientThread = new SocketThread(sock, inFromClient);
                ServerStarter.getInstance().registerClientThread(clientThread);
                ServerStarter.getInstance().startClientThread(clientThread);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
    }

    public boolean isShutdown() {
        return shutdown;
    }

    public void startClientThread(SocketThread clientThread) {
        executorService.submit(clientThread);
    }

    private void registerClientThread(SocketThread clientThread) {
        observable.addObserver(clientThread);
    }

    public void notifyAllClients(final Object message) {
        fairLock.lock();
        try {
            executorService.submit(new MessageBroadcaster(message));
        } finally {
            fairLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void unregisterClientThread(SocketThread clientThread) {
        fairLock.lock();
        try {
            observable.deleteObserver(clientThread);
        } finally {
            fairLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private class MessageBroadcaster implements Runnable {
        private final Object message;

        public MessageBroadcaster(Object message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            fairLock.lock();
            try {
                observable.notifyObservers(message);
            } finally {
                fairLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}

class SocketThread implements Runnable, Observer {
    Socket clientSocket;
    BufferedReader inFromClient;

    public SocketThread(Socket clientSocket, BufferedReader inFromClient) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.inFromClient = inFromClient;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String fromClient;
            while (!ServerStarter.getInstance().isShutdown() && (fromClient = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
                // TODO...prepare message to broadcast
                Object message = new Object();
                ServerStarter.getInstance().notifyAllClients(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ServerStarter.getInstance().unregisterClientThread(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object message) {
        // TODO...handle the message
    }
}
```

When client thread wants to notify other client threads then it asynchronously uses the observable to notify other threads. The observable will call `update()` method of each client thread.

Comment: exactly what i need,but since i ask the question i'm thinking for another solution,can i save the socket for each client(thread) in a hashmap and for broadcasting simply build a dataoutput Stream on those sockets and sending out my message to all exsiting sockets in the hashmap?

Comment: Hmm...you can but I would not prefer that option because why would i want to route my message through the socket again if I can directly deliver it to each thread which all exist in the same JVM. This would have been ok of client threads were existed in different JVMs.